# Discuss the convergence or divergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin^p(n^q)}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to discuss the convergence or divergence of $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin^p(n^q)}{n} \ (p,q＞0)$$
In order to solve this problem, I started with the following simple case in my course material:
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(n^\frac{1}{2023})}{n}$$
Here is a sketch of solution:

For this question, based on a characteristic of the sine function, let's consider partitioning the intervals.

For each positive integer $k$, we can always find an $n$ such that:
$$
k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}<n<k\pi+\frac{3\pi}{4}
$$
In such intervals, $\sin(n)>\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

When $q<1$ in the expression $n^q$, we can find an $n$ for each $k$ such that:
$$
k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}<n^q<k\pi+\frac{3\pi}{4}
$$

This implies that when $q<1$, we have:
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(n^\frac{1}{2023})}{n}>\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{n}
$$
As a result, the series diverges in this case.

However, for the general case, the above method is no longer applicable because:

- When $p$ is not an even number, the selection method mentioned above cannot determine divergence because $\sin(x)$ can take negative values.
- When $q>1$, the same selection method does not guarantee the assumption that "we can always find an $n$ that $k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}<n^q<k\pi+\frac{3\pi}{4}$."

This makes it challenging to continue the discussion. How can I solve this problem?